# RAA elimination and inference a theory ?!

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

Can somebody explain the why if we eliminate `RAA` rule in natural deduction system on propositional logic, why

> ~$(p \wedge $~$p)$ is not inference from the resulting system, but ~~
>   $p \to p$ can deduce from this.

any idea or hint for this type of question is so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume the usual abbreviation : $\lnot p$ for $p \to \bot$.

Here is the proof of $\lnot (p \land \lnot p)$ :

1) $p \land \lnot p$ --- assumed [a]

2) $p$ --- by $\land$-elimination

3) $\lnot p$ --- by $\land$-elimination

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\to$-elimination, with the abbreviation

> 5) $\lnot (p \land \lnot p)$ --- from 1) and 4) by $\to$-introduction and abbreviation, discharging [a].

The proof nowhere uses *RAA*.

---

The *RAA* rule, or rule for indirect proof, can be expresses as :

> $${
> \Gamma,\lnot \varphi \vdash \bot
> \over
> \Gamma \vdash \varphi
> }$$

and is equivalent to *Double Negation* : $\lnot \lnot p \to p$.

---

About : $(p∧ \lnot p) \to q$, we can derive it as follows :

1) $p∧ \lnot p$ --- assumed [a]

2) $p$ --- by $\land$-elimination

3) $\lnot p$ --- by $\land$-elimination

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\to$-elimination

5) $q$ --- from 4) by $\bot$-rule

> 6) $(p∧ \lnot p) \to q$ --- from 1) and 5) by $\to$-introduction, discharging [a].

Neither this proof needs *RAA*.

Comment: Thanks Man ! so if we make is stranger like $ (p \wedge $~p$) \to q$ ? what about this type ?

Comment: there is a mistake on question, please see edited version, sorry

Comment: I think it's very hard, am I right?

Comment: thanks alot. I get it but for formula in my first comment? would you please add it to your answer? thanks a lot professor.

Comment: is it possible to say about this complex one ?

Comment: is it possible make it clear for other examples? thanks

Comment: would you pleas say for my first comment ?